# Copy jsp files directly to installed apps on websphere server

Tags: websphere-6.1

In my previous company, we used to copy jsp files and the class files to the websphere server directly in the path below
C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP70\runtimes\base_v61\profiles\AppSrv01\installedApps\P443Node02Cell

Now, In my present company I dont see the my application under the installedapps directory

Can some one help how can I find the path of the application on server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect to see application in the installedApps, check whether perhaps it's installed on a different Node?

Although what you are doing, a "patch" install, does work I would not advise it as a matter of course. One issue is that you end up with an application that doesn't necessarily match any specific EAR.

Comment: Its getting installed on the right node. When I start the server I get
'[8/17/11 14:23:53:851 EDT] 000000aa FileRepositor A ADMR0010I: Document cells/P443Node02Cell /applications/SBTR.ear/deployments/SBTR/deployment.xml is modified.'